# Self-contained PHP server

Tags: php, sqlite

There used to be a nice little self-contained PHP server floating around called PortableWebAp.  Does anyone know where to find a copy of it?  That thing seems impossible to find.  And, portablewebap.com is not active anymore.

It was super small and came bundled with SQLite3 - it was perfect for desktop-type apps developed in PHP.

I know there are others out there - but, PortableWebAp was (I think) the best.  I could kick myself for losing my copy.

If anyone has a copy, or knows where to find it - please share! :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20080421025821/www.portablewebap.com/download.php) reveals that the latest download file was named PortableWebAp3.5.1.zip.
[Google knows it](http://www.google.com/search?q=PortableWebAp3.5.1.zip) and [here it is](http://www.schirmer.se/_schirmer.se_Album/_DL---verzeichnis/PortableWebAp3.5.1.zip.zip).